# timezone issue with javascript date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

got a timezone issue with a javascript date which displays the day before when changing the timezone from GMT to EST.  I've imported momentjs to help with this although my attempt is failing with the following code.  any suggestions?

original code is

```
thisDate = new Date(myVar);  // original
```

New attempt to correct the timezone difference.

```
thisDate = moment(thisDate).utc().format();
```

Many thanks,

**UPDATE**

```
var myDate = new Date(myVar);
var displayDate = moment(myDate).zone('+0100').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
```

Comment: `thisDate = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second));`

Comment: I've tried that and I get the same problem.  I've assumed your line suggested to try it without momentjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MomentJS is parsing the date as a locale date-time. If no hour is given, it is assuming midnight.

Then, you convert it to UTC, so it is shifted, according to your local time, forward or backwards. If your are in UTC+N, then you will get the previous date.

Check this formats

```
moment(new Date('07-18-2013')).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").toString()
"2013-07-17 21:00"

moment(new Date('07-18-2013 12:00')).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").toString()
"2013-07-18 09:00"

Date()
"Thu Jul 25 2013 14:28:45 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time)"


moment(new Date('07-18-2013 UTC')).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").toString()
"2013-07-18 00:00"


// always "2013-05-23 00:55"
moment(1369266934311).zone('+0100').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
```

Refer to this [documentation.](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)

Update :

```
moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
```

**// "Sunday, February 14th 2010, 3:25:50 pm"**

Comment: should I just add the hour and minutes to it?

Comment: @James Radford. which one you are using

Comment: yeah.. I can confirm the time is 00:00:00

Comment: you want hour, min, sec. change this code  format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') add ss for seconds

Comment: Are you got it @James Radford